# Establish connection with RLink and Rtools

Tags: windows, rlink

Has anyone gotten *RLink* to work with *Rtools* (or even tried)? 
If so a simple step-by-step would be much appreciated !

When attempting to access any *Rtools* functionality through *RLink* I get:

> The following R error was encountered: Error in system(cmd, intern = \
>   !verbose) : 'C:/Program' not found

Background: I'm trying to get data in and out of the *RStan* package with *Mathematica* (mostly because *Mathematica* is the program I've used most for manipulating data and the more I can do in *Mathematica* the less time I'll have to spend learning how to manipulate the data in *R*) and *Rtools* is required for *RStan*.

Thanks for the responses-
Some new info in response to the comments:
I installed R 2.15.3 (since version 3 doesn't work with RLink in Windows yet)
Then:

```
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.15.3"]
```

And that works for the basic RLink functionality.
Through the R command line, I got the required packages installed.
Then restart Mathematica, and check to make sure the packages are installed (which they are) and accessible - at least at the level that `REvaluate["library(Rcpp)"]` and `REvaluate["library(rstan)"]` both seem to work - returning a list of the loaded libraries.
But then either running the "hello world" example from https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started or trying to use any of the rstan commands results in the above error.

Any further thoughts?

Comment: Use it all the time. Be sure you've got correct versions for your envir: it can be pissy about that.

Comment: I don't use either Rtools or R on Windows, but here's an idea: have you tried using an external R installation (through the "RHomeLocation" option of `InstallR`)?  I *think* R 3.0 doesn't work with RLink on Windows, so you'd need to use an older version.

Comment: @Szabolcs Wanted to suggest that too, but was thinking that may be rasher would expand his comment. If one uses the stand-alone R on Windows (but not R 3.x), one can use R's command line prompt too, to install packages (although on Windows, they can also be installed directly by RLink).

Comment: Haven't gotten around to trying this yet (and I'm not using Windows), but have you seen this comment in [the installation instructions](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started)? *"Mainly for Windows users, if Rcpp version is less than 0.10.3, it needs to be installed in a directory without space. So to avoid any issue that might come up if an old version of Rcpp was installed before, just update to the latest version."*  You could try `update.packages()` from the R command line.

Comment: This question is a bit silly, but now that you have an external R installation, have you tried running it separately (not through RLink) and using RStan from it?  Does it work that way?